# Revision Control script with python

Tags: python, bash, system-administration

I am was reading this SO question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388/organization-wide-backup-strategy

And i was interested in implementing this system

> Revision control is handled by a
>   Python script that scans a file system
>   and uploads changed files to a central
>   server. The file system on that server
>   makes extensive use of Unix-style
>   symbolic links - i.e. only one copy of
>   a given file is ever stored,
>   subsequent copies are simply symlinked
>   to. This allows you to have a full
>   file system created for each day's
>   backup but to only use a fraction of
>   the actual disk space it uses (you
>   just need enough space for any files
>   changed since the last backup and to
>   store all those symlinks). This is the
>   general principle that things like the
>   Mac's Time Machine system uses. Users
>   needing to restore an old file can
>   simply browse that file system.

Can anyone give me some guide lines or tutorials or some rready to use script like that in Python . the best thing i would like to see is how to have virtual file system of every day , without using too much space

I am newbie in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync + hard links.

use rsync to maintain a master backup directory.
use cp -al to take daily/weekly/whatever snapshots.

Using hard links means duplicated files will not take up additional space, i.e. each snapshot will only use up the space in the files that have changed.  In addition each snapshot contains a complete copy of the backup and symlinks that get backed up will be preserved.

I have a python wrapper for this that manages the snapshots - keeping a predefined number of daily, weekly, monthly and yearly snapshots, but you can keep this as elaborate or simple as you want.

Great source of inspiration here: http://www.mikerubel.org/computers/rsync_snapshots/

Update:

sample backup:

```
# generate some test data
mkdir /tmp/backup
mkdir documents
date > documents/file1
date > documents/file2

# do the backup
rsync -av --delete documents /tmp/backup/
cp -al /tmp/backup /tmp/backup.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
```

Now you should have a master backup with the current state (/tmp/backup) and a dated backup /tmp/backup..  For the next backup, just run the rsync and cp again:

```
# modify the test data
date >> documents/file1

# do the backup
rsync -av --delete documents /tmp/backup/
cp -al /tmp/backup /tmp/backup.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
```

Note that rsync will only update files that have changed, so in terms of backup time this is optimised.  As you're using hard links for files that are unchanged, it is also very efficient for storage too.

Comment: if i do backups like u said , can i have a same file structure as /home , i don't wan to compress , 1)i want uncompressed backups 2)Will all incremental backups look like same as main backup , i mean when i open file.txt will that open it like it was on that day not. 3)Would u like to share that python wrapper :)

Comment: this is not a compressed backup method; incremental backups will be identical, but you will need to be root to preserve ownerships; my wrapper uses some libraries, which wouldn't work well here, but it shouldn't be too difficult to code up.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [Mercurial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://mercurial.selenic.com/&rct=j&q=mercurial&ei=W3m-Tb-RMcr2sgbd4Z3vBQ&usg=AFQjCNF7tD0P7fC99C8kD2nopBTgsWdp3Q&cad=rja) - a great source control system written in Python. It's also one of teh most popular SCMs these days.

Comment: Actaully i would like to do that by hand written script rather than any ready made software . i mean one py script and running with cron. Though ready software will be better but i want to learn

Comment: @Mahakaal: you have a lot to learn then ;-) Start by learning Python well

Comment: there are many backup solution available on internet but writing a bash script would take only 20 lines and thats it. Though not perfect but things can be done . i was looking for that sort of solution , rather than full fledge package

Comment: @Mahakaal: then your question is too general. If you want, write that bash script in 20 lines and ask how to translate it to Python

Comment: i think for that i again have to ask SO  and then i will post here :)